# How to automatically fill down by multiple?

Tags: excel

I have a column of data that need to be filled. The formula should go like:

```
SUM(A10 + B10)
SUM A20 + B20
SUM A30 + B30
     .     .
     .     .
```

I have no idea on how to do the setup. Appreciate for any help :)

Comment: Just need to fill the column. But the row number must be increased by multiple of 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the [*INDIRECT* worksheet function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INDIRECT-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261). You need to nest it within the SUM function and you'll get what you're after. E.g. assuming you're in a cell in the very first row on a worksheet, you type:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("A" & ROW()*10), INDIRECT("B" & ROW()*10))
```

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use `INDEX` function here, it's not volatile like `INDIRECT` and will still work if you insert rows or columns, e.g. in cell `C2` use this formula copied down

`=SUM(INDEX(A$1:B$1000,ROWS(C$2:C2)*10,0))`

.....or alternatively, this method will actually give you the formula `=SUM(A10,B10)` in the first cell and `=SUM(A20,B20)` in the next cell etc.

Put this formula in C2 and copy down as far as required

`="=SUM(A"&ROWS(C$2:C2)*10&",B"&ROWS(C$2:C2)*10&")"`

Select whole range > Right Click > Copy > Right Click > Paste Special > Values > OK > ENTER

That creates text versions of the required formulas - to convert to actual formulas do an "Edit/Replace" and replace = with =

Answer (score 0):

Use **=SUM(A10,B10)** in the first cell and the drag the cell content to all the below cells if you want to fix a attribute like column number than put a **$** symbol in front of it eg **=SUM($A10,$B10)**. Similarly, for rows use **=SUM(A$10,B$10)**.

Comment: This won't do it. Pay attention to the question. The step of the parameters is 10, not 1. This will fill =SUM(A11,B11) in the row bellow. Then =SUM(A12,B12) and so on...

Answer (score 0):

I would probably do something like this, only because I prefer VBA.

```
Sub FillSheet()
Dim j, k
j = 10
k = 1
  For j = 10 to 500 Step 10   '<<--Starts at 10, then 20, 30, etc up to 500
    Worksheets("YourWorkSheetName").Range("A" & k).Formula = "=SUM(A" & j & ":B" & j & ")"
    k = k +1
  Next j
End Sub
```

Modify according to your requirements. Change "A" if want the formula in another column. Change "500" to however many lines you need.